# Vim 7.4 hybrid line numbers not working (installed via Homebrew)

Tags: homebrew, vi

I recently discovered that Vim 7.4 enables a hybrid number mode, such that if you do `set nu` and `set rnu`, you'll see the absolute line number of the current line and relative line numbers everywhere else (see [here](http://codeyarns.com/2015/03/24/absolute-relative-and-hybrid-line-numbers-in-vim/) and [here](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2013/vims-new-hybrid-line-number-mode/)). I set this up on a Linux machine and it works great. Unfortunately it's not working on my Mac (El Capitan). If I type `:set rnu` I'll get relative numbers with 0 at the cursor line, and if I then type `:set nu` it will switch to only absolute line numbers, unlike what I see on the Linux machine. I have Vim 7.4 installed via Homebrew. How do I get this to work? Do I need to reinstall with some particular setting?

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me. Also using the brew-installed 7.4 version of `vim`. I didn't install `vim` in any particular way or with any particular flags. Have you tried cleaning out your plugins and `.vimrc` to see if you maybe have a conflicting setting?

Comment: Oh. FWIW I already had `:set number` in my `.vimrc` so I was doing `:set relativenumber` -- maybe it's order-dependent?

Comment: @Ian C. Yeah I'll try cleaning out the plugins. I don't think it's order dependent. Either order works fine on my Linux machine and I tried both ways on my Mac

Comment: @IanC. Unfortunately, even changing the names of my .vimrc file and whole .vim folder (where all my plugins are) didn't change the behavior. Really not sure what to check from here. The output of `vim --version` is VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr  5 2016 22:32:58)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1707
Compiled by Homebrew ...etc etc...

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem was not with Vim 7.4, Homebrew, Macs, or any combination of the 3. Just my brain. I was used to `vi` pointing to the `vim` that I want, but in my case `vim` points to the Homebrewed version and `vi` points to the version originally on my Mac, which was Vim 7.3. I usually use `vi` and `vim` interchangeably and that shot me in the foot here. I have `vi` aliased to the Homebrewed Vim now and everything is dandy.

Comment: Ha. Well, thanks for putting me on to `:set relativenumber` -- that's now in my `vimrc` and I'm digging it.

Comment: Good, I'm glad something useful came out of my blinding stupidity :)